# How to swap XML nodes in AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How can I change order in which nodes appear inside their parent? Let's say I want to swap nodes with index 5 and 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var XX:XML =

<root>
    <node index="0" />
    <node index="1" />
    <node index="2" />
    <node index="3" />
    <node index="4" />
    <node index="5" />
    <node index="6" />
    <node index="7" />
    <node index="8" />
    <node index="9" />
</root>

var XL:XMLList = XX.children();

XX.insertChildAfter(XL[5], XL[4]);

var XXL:XMLList = XX.children();

trace(XX.toXMLString());

trace(XL[4] === XXL[4]);
trace(XL[4] === XXL[5]);
trace(XL[4] === XXL[6]);
```

**P.S.** Also, if you wondered how to remove a child node:

```
delete XL[0];

trace(XX.toXMLString());
```

**UPD:** The following code takes the bug we've found into account and works for **any** Flash Player version.

```
var XX:XML =

<root>
    <node index="0" />
    <node index="1" />
    <node index="2" />
    <node index="3" />
    <node index="4" />
    <node index="5" />
    <node index="6" />
    <node index="7" />
    <node index="8" />
    <node index="9" />
</root>

swapNodes(XX, 4, 5);
swapNodes(XX, 0, 9);
trace(XX.toXMLString());

function swapNodes(target:XML, indexa:int, indexb:int):void
{
    // Sanity checks.
    if (!target) return;
    if (indexa < 0) return;
    if (indexb < 0) return;
    if (indexa == indexb) return;

    var anIndex:int;

    // Lets say indexa must be < indexb.
    // Just for our own convenience.
    if (indexb < indexa)
    {
        anIndex = indexa;
        indexa = indexb;
        indexb = anIndex;
    }

    var aList:XMLList = target.children();

    // Last check.
    if (indexb >= aList.length()) return;

    var aNode:XML = aList[indexa];
    var bNode:XML = aList[indexb];
    var abNode:XML = aList[indexb - 1];

    delete aList[indexb];
    target.insertChildBefore(aNode, bNode)

    if (indexb - indexa > 1)
    {
        delete aList[indexa];
        target.insertChildAfter(abNode, aNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems I understand what you wanted to show, but your code doesn't work on topic. It just inserts duplicate of index 4 after index 5 and leaves original node on index 4, but doesn't swap nodes (when node with index 4 comes to place of index 5, and node with index 5 to place of index 4).

Comment: @TimYusupov Did you actually try it? Or you just looked at it and "oh no, that will not work"?

Comment: Of course, I have tried.
Output:
`<root>
  <node index="0"/>
  <node index="1"/>
  <node index="2"/>
  <node index="3"/>
  <node index="4"/>
  <node index="5"/>
  <node index="4"/>
  <node index="6"/>
  <node index="7"/>
  <node index="8"/>
  <node index="9"/>
</root>`

Comment: @TimYusupov For me my code (Flex SDK 4.6 + AIR SDK 21) outputs: <root>
  <node index="0"/>
  <node index="1"/>
  <node index="2"/>
  <node index="3"/>
  <node index="5"/>
  <node index="4"/>
  <node index="6"/>
  <node index="7"/>
  <node index="8"/>
  <node index="9"/>
</root>

Comment: Well, I have outdated version of SDK, but still name of the method `insertChildAfter` doesn't imply action like swapping. Strange.

Comment: @TimYusupov It is not, as well as it doesn't sound like it is going to **copy** the given node prior to inserting. And as long as a node cannot have 2 parents, it leaves its former place and goes to its new place... I thought so, at least. BTW, could you, just for the spirit of it, check, which one of your **index="4"** nodes is original, and which is the clone? Or maybe they both are clones? Or maybe they both are originals?

Comment: How will I properly do that check?

Comment: @TimYusupov You have **XL:XMLList** of original nodes, just compare **XL[4]** against **XX.children()[4]** and **XX.children()[6]**

Comment: So, both comparisons say true. It means both are originals?

Comment: @TimYusupov Ahem... o_O ...yes. It cannot be, but yes. Try === comparison?

Comment: True again on strict comparison :) BTW, I tested this on pure AS3 project for Flash Player on Flex SDK 4.6 (not an AIR Project).

Comment: @TimYusupov Ok, I performed a number of tests and can confirm it (see the updated code block): Flash Player up to 11.2 outputs **true false true**, while Flash Player 32+ (which corresponds AIR SDK 21+) outputs **false true false**. That means, this functionality actually changed somewhere in between. Since I believe that double XML node is a severe malfunction, I propose to count it as a bugfix.

Comment: Wow. Strange method. Should I trust it in order to solve my task? Even if I will use it on updated version. Maybe other more elegant ways to solve it? If so, post another anwser. Thanks!

Comment: @TimYusupov Taking bugs into account and backward compatibility has its price. You can take the first version and have faith that no one will run it in outdated Flash Player.